# Nodejs: Loop Through File and Parse PDFs using Callback in Sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, asynchronous

I am new to node so am struggling quite a bit with the Async nature of it.

I am trying to create a script that will parse the pdfs inside a directory and output them in txt format in another directory.

To do this, I am using fs and pdf2json npm packages. I am passing the parseData function as a callback in the loopingFiles function. The only problem I am having is the async nature of node.

It will loop through all the files at the same time and the output is then a jumbled mess in the last file index.

I would like to process this synchronously such that it will wait once the data is finished parsing to write to the txt and then loop again.

I have tried promises but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);

var parseData = function(pdf, index) {
  txtFile = "/Users/janet/node/pdf/Destination/".concat(index.toString().concat(".txt"))
  pdfFile = "/Users/janet/node/pdf/Source/".concat(pdf);
  pdfParser.loadPDF(pdfFile);
    // Parsing the pdf file in question
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
      fs.writeFile(txtFile, pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
});
  };



var loopingFiles = function(callback) {
  fs.readdir("/Users/janet/node/pdf/Source", function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    files.forEach( function(file, index) {
      callback(file, index);
    });
  };
  });
};


loopingFiles(parseData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var fs = require("fs"),
  PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this, 1);

var parseData = function(pdfs, index = 0) {
  // finished
  if (index >= pdfs.length) return;
  let pdf = pdfs[index];
  txtFile = "/Users/janet/node/pdf/Destination/".concat(
    index.toString().concat(".txt")
  );
  pdfFile = "/Users/janet/node/pdf/Source/".concat(pdf);
  // Parsing the pdf file in question
  pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => {
    console.error(errData.parserError)
    // not sure if you want to call this here to keep going or not
    parseData(pdfs, index + 1);
  });
  pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
    fs.writeFile(txtFile, pdfParser.getRawTextContent(), function() {
      // when we're all done, call this function again, with the index of the next pdf
      parseData(pdfs, index + 1);
    });
  });
  pdfParser.loadPDF(pdfFile);
};

var loopingFiles = function(callback) {
  fs.readdir("/Users/janet/node/pdf/Source", function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      callback(files, 0);
    }
  });
};

loopingFiles(parseData);
```

the main difference is passing the whole array of pdfs to the function with an index, and only calling that function again with an incremented index once the current one is completed